# Как передать в метод ссылку на класс, не создавая его экземпляра?

Tags: java, libgdx, kotlin

У меня есть пара кнопок, на которых нужно отследить нажатие. Каждая переключает экран на новый класс. Я хочу сделать с помощью метода, передавая в него ссылку на класс, на который переключает кнопка. Проблема в том что экземпляр класса создается в вызове метода, а мне нужно чтобы создавался после отпуска кнопки.

Comment: Смешались в кучу люди, кони... Надо передать ссылку на класс или все же генерировать событие отпуска кнопки? Вопрос то в чем?

Comment: попробуй сделать метод статичним

Comment: Извините, а что это даст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну а в чем собственно говоря проблема то? Передавайте тип `Class`

```
public void callListener(Class clz)  {
    //blah-blah
    //через Java reflection создаем экземпляр класса clz и все такое
}
```

Вызываем так: `callListener(MyListener.class)`